# Ember.js + Mirage: pulling a mocked relationship in integration test

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli-mirage

I have a component that makes use of `this.get('model.property')`, and it works as intended.

For my integration tests I'm using Mirage, which has worked for all my other tests (integration tests included), however when I test this specific component I get:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

This is what my test looks like:

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit'
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile'
import { startMirage } from 'app/initializers/ember-cli-mirage'
import Ember from 'ember'

moduleForComponent('summary-card', 'Integration | Component | summary card', {
  integration: true,
  beforeEach() {
    this.server = startMirage()
  },
  afterEach() {
    this.server.shutdown()
  }
})

test('it renders', function(assert) {
  const customer = this.server.create('customer')
  const location = this.server.create('location', { customer })
  const manufacturer = this.server.create('manufacturer')
  const model = this.server.create('device-model', { manufacturer })
  this.server.createList('device', 5, { model, customer, location })

  const loc = Ember.Object.create(location)
  this.set('model', loc)
  this.render(hbs`{{summary-card model=model model-name=model.name tag='location' belongs-to='customer' has-many='device'}}`);

  assert.equal(this.$('h1').text().trim(), 'Location 0', 'should be titled Location 0')

});
```

And basically, my `summary-card.js` has something like this:

```
this.get('model.' + belongs).then(relationship => {...})
```

where `belongs` is simply the value of whatever `belongs-to` is set to when the component is invoked.

I'm a bit puzzled, as it seems like the mock model I'm passing to my test isn't really representing the model in the same way it does when running `ember s` (I'm using Mirage for development purposes as well). Is there anywhere where I can find out more about what's exactly going on there?

Thank you!

---

P.S. I've also tried to use the `location` object as is provided by `server.create()`, and I get a slightly different error:

`TypeError: _this.get(...).then is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

Well, by reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38525930/543423), I managed to find my own solution, which works really well:

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit'
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile'
import Ember from 'ember'

moduleForComponent('summary-card', 'Integration | Component | summary card', {
  integration: true
})

test('it renders', function(assert) {
  this.inject.service('store', {as: 'store'})
  let location

  Ember.run(() => {
    location = this.store.createRecord('location', {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Location 0',
      customer: this.store.createRecord('customer', {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Customer 0'
      }),
      devices: [this.store.createRecord('device', {id: 1})]
    })
  })

  this.set('model', location)
  this.render(hbs`
    {{#summary-card model=model model-name=model.name tag='location' belongs-to='customer' has-many='device'}}
      <div class='test-content'>Test Content</div>
    {{/summary-card}}
  `)
```

Basically, I have opted for using the store directly, rather than using Mirage, and it works!