# 'this' undefined only from component integration test

Tags: javascript, ember.js, qunit, ember-cli-mirage

This is an Ember component that will need `this` at some point:

```
export default Component.extend({
  filteredSubs: computed.filter('model.subs', function() {
    // this will always return true in development http://localhost:4200/dummy
    // but will always return false in test because 'this' becomes undefined
    return this;
  })
});
```

`Dummy` has a one-to-many relationship to `Sub`:

```
export default Model.extend({
  subs: hasMany('sub')
});

export default Model.extend({
  dummy: belongsTo('dummy')
});
```

This test fails but shouldn't:

```
test('it renders', function(assert) {
  let dummy = server.create('dummy');
  server.create('sub', { dummy });

  this.set('dummy', dummy);
  this.render(hbs`{{show-dummy model=dummy}}`);

  assert.equal(this.$().text().trim(), 'Hi! There are 1 sub-dummies');
});
```

> not ok 13 Chrome 63.0 - Integration | Component | show dummy: it renders
>
> actual: Hi! There are 0 sub-dummies
>
> expected: Hi! There are 1 sub-dummies

- Not sure if this could be an Ember bug or ember-cli-mirage bug,
- I have isolated the issue in a fresh repo https://github.com/stephanebruckert/ember-bug-16052
- Also posted on https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/16052

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from an unfortune sequense of falsy assumptions.

The first assumption of you is that `this` inside a `Ember.computed.filter` should be the corresponding object. I'm not 100% sure this is documented behaviour, and personally wouldnt rely on it. If you need full access to `this` I would go with a simple `Ember.computed`.

However your primary mistake is in your test. And this also explains why you only have this problem in testing. Your directly using a mirage model as `model` for your component:

```
let dummy = server.create('dummy');
server.create('sub', {
  dummy
});

this.set('dummy', dummy);

this.render(hbs`{{show-dummy model=dummy}}`);
```

Here you assume that the result of `server.create`, a mirage model, is in some ways similar to a `ember-data` model. *It is not!* In fact, a mirage model is not even an `ember` object! So you can't use `.get` or `.set` on it, or anything you defined on your model, and definitly should not use it ever as an model für component testing. Instead you should use mirage as data-source for your `ember-data` models.

The question why `this` is undefined if your model is a mirage model leads to [this line in `ember-cli-mirage`](https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage/blob/6a9c8489368c86af4ca4b2c15052aff4ebbe4303/addon/orm/collection.js#L131):

```
filter(f) {
  let filteredModels = this.models.filter(f);

  return new Collection(this.modelName, filteredModels);
}
```

where the `this`-context gets lost. Basically mirage is overriding the `.filter` function on their custom array-like structure, and doesnt ensure to keep the `this`-context.

Comment: Thanks for that @Lux. I'm now using `filteredSubs: computed('dummy.subs', function() { return this.get('dummy.subs').filter(s => s); })` instead. Whether `.filter` should keep the context for `this` or not is now being discussed on the ember-cli-mirage issue https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage/issues/1256

Comment: Also @Lux what's your recommendation to "fake" data as part of a component test? Most people use Mirage's `server.create` but I have to agree that it's sometimes acting weirdly, as you mentioned we don't always have access to `.get` or `.set`. Ty!

Comment: I dont think thats common. `server.create` is common to produce test data, but you always should wrap them with real ember-data models! `store.push` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: You are right. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45578787/1515819) to be the best way to “mock objects” inside component integration tests, as compared to Mirage’s `server.create` or Ember’s `EmberObject.create` which would not work with objects that contain relationships